# Import module into current scope?

Tags: module, typescript

The modules have very long names (they make names of the imported functions three times longer then needed), for example: `mapconcat` looks `Project.Utils.mapconcat` is there any way to import this function and use it w/o fully qualifying it by the module name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always do :

```
var x = Project.Utils.mapconcat;
// now use x in place of mapconcat
```

PS: you can use the import statement to create an alias for a module

```
import pu = Project.Utils;
// now: 
pu.mapconcat
```

This is assuming Utils is a module name (and not a class).

Comment: I think it has also meaning that modules into the current scope can't by merged.